# Как обработать Nullpointer Exception и продолжить обработку файла?

Tags: java, json

У меня есть цикл обработки json  файла на корректность всех полей. При прогоне всех group,если в одной из полей групп встретился null, то встречается Nullpointer Exception. Моя задача именно корректно обрабатывать эти null в полях, поэтому нужно чтобы, если какое-то поле в одном из объектов null, то все равно входить в цикл для обработки этого null
Мой код

```
  for (StudyGroup group : collection) {//детальная проверка файла на корректность
                            String line;
                            try {
                            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                            if (group.getStudentsCount().equals(null)) {
                                System.out.println("Незаполнено поле StudentCount у группы с id " + group.getId());
                                System.out.println("Хотите заполнить данный объект?В ином случае он не загрузиться(true/false)");
                                try {
                                    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                                        line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
                                    } else {
                                        return null;
                                    }
                                    if (line.equals("true")) {
                                        System.out.print("Введите значение для поля StudentsCount: ");
                                        line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
                                        if (line.equals("end")) {
                                            System.out.println("Добавление элемента остановлено.");
                                            return null;
                                        }
                                        if (group.setStudentsCount(Long.valueOf(line))) {
                                            System.out.println("Поле StudentsCount дописано");
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (line.equals("false")) {

                                        collection.remove(group);
                                        System.out.println("Тк вы не заполнили поле объект был пропущен");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println("Ошибка ввода поля StudentsCount, попробуйте еще раз или напишите end");
                                }
                           catch (NullPointerException e) {
                               System.out.println("Беда");
                                  }
  }
```

Мой Json

```
[{
    "id":6984763508754014508,
    "name":"P3111",
    "coordinates":{
        "x":32,
        "y":360.0},
    "creationDate": {
      "date":{
        "year":2021,
        "month":5,
        "day":5},
      "time":{
          "hour":11,
          "minute":20,
          "second":30,
          "nano":682866300}},
    "expelledStudents":5, 
    "formOfEducation":"DISTANCE_EDUCATION",
    "semesterEnum":"FIRST",
    "groupAdmin":{
        "name":"Маша",
        "passportID":"123",
        "eyeColor":"BLACK",
        "hairColor":"BLACK",
        "nationality":"USA"}}]
```

Comment: больше всего порадовала вот эта строка group.getStudentsCount().equals(null)

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо изменил на group.getStudentsCount()==null  и все стало работать

Comment: @Дмитрий, радоваться тут не нужно. Для этого можешь сходить в цирк или на комедию в кино. На твоем месте было бы правильнее ОБЪЯСНИТЬ человеку, что так писать не стоит и почему не стоит.

Comment: @Artur Vartanyan я это уже сделал, даже по комментарию видно, что помогло. мало того,я даже ответ написал, где указал еще несколько проблем. в чем вопрос?

Comment: @Дмитрий, человеку, который только учиться надо показывать и объяснять почему так писать лучше не стоит. Вот ты ему написал что `больше всего порадовала вот эта строка group.getStudentsCount().equals(null) `, а он взял и поменял на `==`. Ты думаешь он что-то понял из того, что сделал? Ему бы объяснить в данном случае, сориентировать и подсказать где что почитать. Например предложить разобраться с классом `Object` и его методами. Показать разницу между `equals()` и `==`. А то приучаете начинающих тупо копипастить, по итогу подход у обучающего к разработке складывается как к кубик-рубику.

Comment: @Дмитрий, в принципе, исходя из его ответа ниже, видно, что он ничего толком то и не понял. Копи-паст и едем дальше...

Comment: @Artur Vartanyan разбираться или нет - персональный выбор каждого. если непонятно и есть желание разобраться - можно задавать уточняющие вопросы. если такого желания нет, то я ничего сделать не могу.  телепатически обучать я пока не умею, простите

Answer (score 1):

Изменил на group.getStudentsCount()==null и все стало работать! Скорее всего ошибка была в том, что equals подходит для объектов, а null не является объектом. Сл-но если напишем == то все заработает.

Comment: нет, ошибка была не в этом. ошибка в том, что вы никогда не получите true. в первом случае, когда выражение group.getStudentsCount() не равен null, то справедливо получаем false. во втором случае когда выражение group.getStudentsCount() равен null, получается, что мы у null пытаемся вызвать метод (equals), а такая попытка приводит к одному результату - nullpointerexception

Comment: Null не то что не является обьектом, он является признаком отсутствия обьекта.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае писать логику программы на `try-catch` не лучший вариант. Проверяйте все значения на null перед их использованием.

Comment: что означает выражение: "Писать логику программы на try-catch не лучший вариант."?! `try-catch` - придуман для того, чтобы его использовали. Он отлично подходит для обработки ошибок и в том числе для `NullPointerException`. Не пишите общие ответы. Старайтесь отвечать и комментировать свои решения сугубо по конкретному вопросу. Ибо, если, в данной ситуации `try-catch` не лучшее решение, не стоит писать о том, что его использовать вовсе не стоит.

Comment: @ArturVartanyan конкретизировал для данного вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Все равно это нормально работать не будет. Причина - удаление элемента из коллекции в процессе итерации. Так делать нельзя (по крайней мере тем способом, который у вас). Удаление элементов из коллекции - в процессе не очень хорошая практика в целом, но , если уж очень надо, то используйте итератор.

Кроме того, возвращать null - антипаттерн. Не делайте так никогда. В этом случае есть 3 решения: выбросить исключение, использовать паттрен null object , либо использовать optional.

Вам советовали использовать валидацию, не писать логику на базе try-catch, попробуйте хоть иногда прислушаться к тому, что говорят, раз уж сами просите помочь. Это не глупые советы. Ваш код с простейшей логикой превратился в спагетти благодаря глубокой вложенности. Запомните, что главное - читаемость кода, потому как машина исполнит любой, а вот вы будете вынуждены дебажить его неделями (как и произошло).

Раз вы хотите реализовать логику именно таким способом, то попробуйте хотя бы избавиться от дублирующей логики, написав отдельные методы. Например, так:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Function;
import lombok.Data;

public class Parser {

    private final Scanner scanner;

    public Parser() {
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
    
    public void start(Iterable<StudyGroup> collection) {
        Iterator<StudyGroup> iterator = collection.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            StudyGroup group = iterator.next();
            if (group.getStudentsCount() != null) continue;
            System.out.println("Незаполнено поле StudentCount у группы с id " + group.getId());
            System.out.println("Хотите заполнить данный объект? В ином случае он не загрузиться(true/false)");
            if (parseAndEquals(Boolean::valueOf, true)) {
                System.out.print("Введите значение для поля StudentsCount: ");
                if (parseAndEquals(s -> s, "end")) {
                    System.out.println("Добавление элемента остановлено.");
                    break;
                }
                parse(Long::valueOf).ifPresent(line -> {
                    group.setStudentsCount(line);
                    System.out.println("Поле StudentsCount дописано");
                });
            } else {
                iterator.remove();
                System.out.println("Тк вы не заполнили поле объект был пропущен");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    private <T> boolean parseAndEquals(Function<String, T> converter, Object arg) {
            return parse(converter).map(result->result.equals(arg)).orElseGet(()->false);
    }
    private <T> Optional<T> parse(Function<String, T> converter) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(converter.apply(scanner.nextLine().trim()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

}
```

Дебажить придется вам, потому как тестов не завезли, а разобраться в вашем коде уже достаточно сложно.